# SQL select MAX(COUNT)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select the user who has the MAX microposts count:

```
SELECT "name", count(*) FROM "users" 
  INNER JOIN "microposts" ON "microposts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
  GROUP BY users.id
```

and this returns

```
"Delphia Gleichner";15
"Louvenia Bednar IV";10
"Example User";53
"Guadalupe Volkman";20
"Isabella Harvey";30
"Madeline Franecki II";40
```

But I want to select only `"Example User";53`, (user who has MAX microposts count)

I tried to add `HAVING MAX(count*)` but  this didn't work.

Comment: Do a subselect which returns the max micropost count and add this into the where/having if you are doing a group by

Comment: It *is* important. No two DBMSes are alike in their implementation of the SQL "standard".

Comment: `HAVING` is just a where clause applied to the aggregate column of the `GROUP BY`: so you need an operator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd try with a ORDER BY max DESC LIMIT 1, where maximum is the count(*) field. Something like:

```
SELECT "name", count(*) maximum FROM "users" 
   INNER JOIN "microposts" ON "microposts"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY maximum DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I dont' have mysql available now, so I'm doing this on the paper (and it might not work), but it's just an orientation.

Comment: but probably there is one more way using MAX function

Comment: This works if there are no ties for the maximum. If there is then you are getting rid of the other maximums.

Comment: What happens if you want to show only the "name" and not the "users" column? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT x.name, MAX(x.count)
FROM (
 SELECT "name", count(*)
  FROM "users" INNER JOIN "microposts" ON "microposts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
  GROUP BY users.id
) x
GROUP BY x.name
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, you can try:

```
SELECT "name", MAX(count_num) FROM 
(SELECT "name", count(*) as count_num
FROM "users" INNER JOIN "microposts" ON "microposts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
GROUP BY users.id) x
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
SELECT "name", count(*) 
FROM "users" 
INNER JOIN "microposts" ON "microposts"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(microposts) = (SELECT COUNT(microposts) 
                         FROM   users
                         GROUP  BY microposts
                         ORDER  BY COUNT(microposts) DESC 
                         LIMIT  1)
```

Didn't test it, but it might work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 "name", count(*) AS ItemCount FROM "users" 
INNER JOIN "microposts" ON "microposts"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY ItemCount DESC
```